# I web scraped following inspected tag and class and it returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information (titles, topic, dates...) from this page http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/594418/Greenpeace/#vars!date=2050-10-20_02:52:36! using beautifulsoup. When I print it out to check if it similar to what I inspected on the web, it returns "None".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/594418/Greenpeace#vars!date=2050-10-20_02:52:36!').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

events = soup.find('div', class_ = 'tl-story-block tl-story-category-view-standard tl-sb-low-height')
print(events)
```

Can you guys help me with this problem? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the page uses dynamic javascript to load the events. So you won't be able to accomplish it using `requests`. Instead you should use selenium with a webdriver to load all the events before scraping.

You can try downloading ChromeDriver executable [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# configure driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"  # Change this to your path if not same folder
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

driver.get('http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/594418/Greenpeace#vars!date=2050-10-20_02:52:36!')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
events = soup.find_all('div', class_='tl-story-block tl-story-category-view-standard tl-sb-low-height')


for event in events:
    topic = event.find('h5')
    date = event.find('h4')
    title = event.find('h3')

    print(title.text, ' - ',  date.text, ' - ', topic.text)
```

### Outputs

```
Woolworths’ commitment to 100% renewable electricity by 2025  -  November 2020  -  Climate
Bunnings commits to 100% renewable electricity by 2025  -  October 2020  -  Climate
Supermarket chain ALDI commits to to purchase 100% of its electricity from...  -  August 2020  -  Climate
Italian giant UniCredit to phase out coal by 2028  -  August 2020  -  Climate
Greenpeace Spain wins court case to stop dismantling of Low Emissions Zone...  -  June 2020  -  Toxics
Greenpeace NL wins court case against Dutch state for oil rig protest  -  June 2020  -  Climate
Senegalese government reject 52 new  industrial fishing licenses  -  June 2020  -  Oceans
...
```

Comment: I run it and it works now, thank you so much for the help, have a good day!